# One-To-Many - Navigation property not populating

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am unable to get the navigation property to populate when I perform a linq query. Here the objects and code I am using.

```
public class Room
{
    public int LobbyId { get; set; }
    public RoomId LobbyObj { get; set; }
    
    public ICollection<RoomBase> RoomBases { get; set; }
}

public class RoomBase
{
    public int RoomBaseId { get; set; }

    public int LobbyId { get; set; }
    public RoomId LobbyObj { get; set; }

    public int StageId { get; set; }
    public RoomId StageObj { get; set; }

    public int RoomId { get; set; }
    public RoomId RoomObj { get; set; }
    
    public Room Room { get; set; }
}

public class RoomId
{
    public int RoomNumber { get; set; }
}

modelBuilder.Entity<RoomId>().HasKey(p => p.RoomNumber);

modelBuilder.Entity<RoomBase>().HasKey(p => p.RoomBaseId);
modelBuilder.Entity<RoomBase>().HasIndex(u => new { u.LobbyId, u.RoomId, u.StageId }).IsUnique();

modelBuilder.Entity<RoomBase>(u =>
{
    u.Property(e => e.RoomId);
    u.HasOne(e => e.RoomObj)
        .WithOne().HasForeignKey<RoomBase>(e => e.RoomId);
});
modelBuilder.Entity<RoomBase>(u =>
{
    u.Property(e => e.StageId);
    u.HasOne(e => e.StageObj)
        .WithOne().HasForeignKey<RoomBase>(e => e.StageId);
});
modelBuilder.Entity<RoomBase>(u =>
{
    u.Property(e => e.LobbyId);
    u.HasOne(e => e.LobbyObj)
        .WithOne().HasForeignKey<RoomBase>(e => e.LobbyId);
});

modelBuilder.Entity<Room>().HasKey(p => p.LobbyId);
modelBuilder.Entity<Room>()
    .HasMany(c => c.RoomBases)
    .WithOne(e => e.Room);
modelBuilder.Entity<Room>(u =>
{
    u.Property(e => e.LobbyId);
    u.HasOne(e => e.LobbyObj)
        .WithOne().HasForeignKey<Room>(e => e.LobbyId);
});
```

Here is the linq query:

```
context.Rooms.Include(x => x.RoomBases)
             .Include(x => x.LobbyObj)
             .ToList();
```

**Summary**

- Room.LobbyId - Primary Key
- Room.LobbyId > RoomId.RoomNumber - Foreign Key
- RoomBase.RoomBaseId - Primary Key
- { RoomBase.LobbyId, RoomBase.StageId, RoomBase.RoomId } - Unique index
- RoomBase.LobbyId > RoomId.RoomNumber - Foreign Key
- RoomBase.StageId > RoomId.RoomNumber - Foreign Key
- RoomBase.RoomId > RoomId.RoomNumber - Foreign Key
- RoomId.RoomNumber - Primary Key

Neither RoomBases nor LobbyObj is populated so it appears I am missing something but I am unable to see what it is. I suspect its the relationship between RoomBase and Room as the "RoomBases" table in the migration script has an extra column called "RoomLobbyId"?

Comment: try adding virtual to the variable declarations.  `public virtual ICollection<RoomBase> RoomBases { get; set; }`

Comment: At first you have to  select appropriate names for your classes and primary keys. Everything looks very messy.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @hijinxbassist this has helped along with fixing several other silly mistakes I have made.